# Add items to array while looping without causing infinite loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I' trying to add duplicate items to an array while looping through it:

Adding it to the end causes an infitie loop:

```
  site.pages.each do |page|
    new_page = page.dup
    new_page.data['permalink'] = File.join('/app', page.url)
    puts new_page.data['permalink']
    puts ''
    site.pages << new_page
  end
```

so does adding it to the beginning.

```
  site.pages.each do |page|
    new_page = page.dup
    new_page.data['permalink'] = File.join('/app', page.url)
    puts new_page.data['permalink']
    puts ''
    site.pages.unshift(new_page)
  end
```

Comment: Create a copy and add to that instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding to an Array while Iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232788/adding-to-an-array-while-iterating)

Answer (score 1):

I would create all the duplicates first and then add them to the array in a second step.

```
new_pages = site.pages.map do |page|
  new_page = page.dup
  new_page.data['permalink'] = File.join('/app', page.url)
end
site.pages += new_pages
```